# Definite integral containing Bessel functions

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am stuck in calculating the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(kr)J_1(kr_0)\exp\left(-it\sqrt{gk}\right)dk$$
Is it possible to use residue theorem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integral does not admit a closed-form in standard special functions for $r \not= r_0$.

Comment: @Sasha: so I have to use numerical integration.